# Convergence in Probability with respect to expectation and variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Here, $({X_n})_{n\geq1}$ is a sequence of random variables .

Result  :  $$ {X_n}  \rightarrow X $$ if $E(X_n) \rightarrow E(X)$  and $ Var(X_n)\rightarrow Var(X)$ as $ n\rightarrow \infty $ .

Take any $ \varepsilon > 0.$

$$ \implies P[ | X_n-X| > \varepsilon ] \\ \\ 
\implies P [ | X_n -X|^2> \varepsilon^2 ]  \leq \frac{E(X_n-X)^2}{\varepsilon^2} \\ \\ 
 =   \frac{[E(X_n)-E(X)]^2+ E[(X_n-E(X_n)]^2-E[(X-E(X)]^2}{\varepsilon^2 } . $$

I am not able to understand the last step .

I tried many ways but couldn't reach the above equation .

Comment: "We have, Since, $X_n\to  X$." does not make sense.

Comment: I have edited.  We need to prove it ,i.e. $X_n \rightarrow X$ if $E(X_n) \rightarrow E(X)$ and $Var(X_n)\rightarrow Var(X)$ .     Last term equates to 0 as Expectation and Variance converges as above .  Hence, we can say $X_n \rightarrow X $ .  Problem is on last step . If you somehow can prove the last equation , then we can easily prove the result .

Comment: We cannot prove the last equation because it is wrong (unless $\operatorname{Var}(X)=\operatorname{Cov}(X_n,X)$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that for any r.v.s $X,Y\in L_2$,
$$
\mathsf{E}[X-Y]^2=(\mathsf{E}[X-Y])^2+\operatorname{Var}(X-Y).
$$
Then the equality you're interested in is incorrect in general because
$$
\operatorname{Var}(X-Y)\ne \operatorname{Var}(X)-\operatorname{Var}(Y)
$$
unless $\operatorname{Var}(Y)=\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$. Take, for example, $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y=2X$. Then
$$
1=\operatorname{Var}(X-Y)\ne \operatorname{Var}(X)-\operatorname{Var}(Y)=-3.
$$

---

Since
$$
\mathsf{E}[X-X_n]^2=(\mathsf{E}[X_n-X])^2+\operatorname{Var}(X_n)+\operatorname{Var}(X)-2\operatorname{Cov}(X_n,X),
$$
convergence in prob. follows if, in addition, $\operatorname{Cov}(X_n,X)\to \operatorname{Var}(X)$.

Comment: What step? The equality stated in the question is wrong. As shown in the other answer, convergence of the expectations and variances is not sufficient.

Comment: $\mathsf{E}X_n-\mathsf{E}X=\mathsf{E}[X_n-X]$.

Comment: Here, in your argument $(X_n)$ does not converge to $X$ .

Comment: I don't know how your argument is correct since ,my professor used this result in many problems without even referring to $Cov(X_n,X)$ .

Answer (score 0):

I read the question as follows:

$EX_n \to EX$ and $var (X_n) \to var (X)$ implkies $X_n \to X$ in probability.

If this is what you are stating then it is false. Let $X$ have a standard normal distribution and take $X_n=-X$ for all $n$ to get a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

Basically he rewrites the RHS of the markov inequality using the variance terms thus to show that if you have convergence in $E(\cdot)$  and in $Var(\cdot)$ then the whole RHS of Markov inequality converges to $0$ for any choice of $\epsilon>0$ . 
In particular he uses the artificial expansion (only adding and subtracting $E(X_n)$ ):

> $\ E[(X_n - X)^2]=E[((X_n - E(X_n))+(E(X_n)-X))^2]$,

Which then expanded gives the desired equality.

To use convergence in variance and quadratic mean you should use the following facts,

> $E(X_n -E(X_n))^2=Var(X_n)$
>
> $E(X -E(X))^2=Var(X)$

Then use

> $E(E(X))=E(X)$

Finally if you let $n\rightarrow \infty \,,$ then you  have convergence for any choice of $\epsilon$ .

Comment: "Which then expanded gives the desired equality"  . I want to prove to get  the desired inequality .

Comment: There is nothing to prove there,but just a square of a binomial $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$

Comment: Recheck , I think you are missing something .

Comment: I am sorry to say so, but it's correct. You should be able to see that $a=(X_n-E(X_n)) \, \,, b=(E(X_n)-X)$. Then do your math and you will get exactly $(X_n-X)^2 \,\, i.e. X_n^2+X^2-2X_nX$

Comment: See ,answer of @d.k.o. who proved that my result to be false . If you think that result is true ,then try to show  it by doing calculations . Now, I myself think that my result is false ,although my result was given by my  professor ,who might have forgotten to add the fact that $$Cov(X_n,X)\rightarrow Var(X) $$ .